# Issue with $_GET being empty despite a valid URL parameter in PHP

Tags: php, url, url-parameters, superglobals

I'm currently trying to pass a URL parameter to a PHP page on my local server, but I'm facing an issue with the `$_GET` superglobal that appears to be empty despite a valid URL parameter.

Here's a summary of the situation:

1. I have a link on my main page pointing to `article.php` with a URL parameter, for example: `http://localhost:5500/blog/article.php?id=1`
2. In `article.php`, I'm using `$_GET['id']` to retrieve the value of the ID passed in the URL.

However, `isset($_GET['id'])` returns `false`, and `var_dump($_GET)` displays `array(0)`, which is unexpected.

**Example code in `article.php`:**

```php
<?php
include("config.php");

var_dump($_GET);  // Displays the data of the $_GET superglobal

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $article_id = $_GET['id'];

    // ... (remaining code)
} else {
    echo 'Article ID not specified.';
}

$connexion->close();
?>
```

Here is my `config.php` :

```php
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "****";
$database = "basename";

$connect = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);

if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Connexion aborted : " . $connect->connect_error);
}
?>
```

**What I've checked so far:**

- The URL is correct.
- The link is correctly formed with a URL parameter.
- No apparent URL rewriting or redirection.

---

**My question:**

What could be the reasons for `$_GET` being empty despite a valid URL parameter? Is there anything I should check or additional configurations to consider?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Although it *could* be [turned off](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) I would rather look at whatever config.php

Comment: @YourCommonSense If turned off, `$_GET` will not be created at all.

Comment: Agree, something is probably going on in config.php which is affecting it. Try to provide a [mre] of the issue

Comment: @ADyson my current code is already in the question

Comment: The code of config.php is _not_ in your question. That's why we asked to see it! But `include("config.php");` means that the config.php code will be executed with the article.php script. We need to see if it's causing the $_GET problem, because it's hard to see what else would be.

Comment: @ADyson now in the question

Comment: Thanks. Ok so it's probably not that then. But at least we know

Comment: By the way, why are you using port 5500?

Comment: @Olivier My Live Server use this

Comment: And what is "My Live Server"?

Comment: @Olivier https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yandeu.five-server

Comment: So you're using a non-standard web server, observe a strange behavior, but don't say a word about it?

Comment: @Olivier You think that’s the problem ?

Comment: Of course it can be the problem. That's the only logical explanation.

Comment: What should I use instead ?

Comment: Ever heard of [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)?

Comment: But maybe we should wait for the documentation of this five-server: [Will be available soon.](https://github.com/yandeu/five-server#:~:text=Will%20be%20available%20soon.)  

Comment: @Luuk That was the broblem. I didn't want to use xampp out of laziness at having to work in htdocs, but I won't be tempted again.

Comment: There are alternatives to XAMP, see:  [php.net: Installation and Configuration](https://www.php.net/install)

Comment: You don't have to work in htdocs, you can make Apache serve files from any folder you choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My dev-server wasn’t able to pass URL parameters.

Comment: It wrks now, but I cannot mark it as answered

Comment: Give it time. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer